# SQLite and variable columns

Tags: android, android-sqlite, store

I have an app which is essentially a big form, but one page of that form is variable, depending on the choice of the user. There are about 50 different pages and each one has a particular list and number of possible user inputs.

Since I want to store the data in a SQLite database, how should I proceed? Should I create columns for every possible input and just store nothing on the fields that are not used? Or is it possible to adapt the database to the data being stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a lot to go on here, but I'd say create a table for the form, a table for each page, and a table for each one-to-many list.

For example, an invoice requires two tables; one for the invoice, and one for the invoice line items.  A "docket" or "customer" record might contain all of the invoices.

Make `FormID` a Primary Key in the first table, and a foreign key in the `Pages` table.  Make `"Page[n]ID"` a foreign key in those tables where there are lists of things that you need to attach to the relevant page.

Comment: I am kind of a noob in SQLite yet, but If I understood correctly, you are suggesting to create the tables that will exist for sure and then "connect" them (through the keys) to other tables that the code should create depending on needs?

So that means that the "variable" tables will only be created If they are used by the program?

Comment: The tables will exist from the start, but records may not be added for specific pages, if they are not required by the user's selections.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Complete sense! That's exactly what I need!

Thanks, now I'll just go and learn some more SQLite, I need it!

Answer (score 1):

consider what fields you actually need to use in queries. hopefully that set is small or at least manageable. for the rest of the fields, store them in single column. e.g., as JSON string of key value pairs.

no, relational databases cannot "adapt" to variable columns. your only other option is to define a column for every single possible field as you suggested. however, doing that is not only going to be burdensome to begin with, but maintenance is going to be a nightmare as the forms are modified in the future.