# How to store data from different pages in the same row in an SQLite in Qt?

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

Currently I am working on a Qt project where I have created GUI for user registration form. Once user submits the form it redirects to a new page where user has to select one among multiple choices and record the choice in the database. There are tens of pages where user has to select a particular choice.

Right now I am storing user registration details in a table created using SQLite database. I want to store user choice for different tests in the columns next to the user registration. But since each page in Qt is written like different class, how can I synchronise/club all the test results with user registration form in Qt/C++?

Please note: 
I have gone through following Stack Overflow pages.

1) [SQLite and variable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582536/sqlite-and-variable-columns)
2) [C++ static class for data storing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111944/c-static-class-for-data-storing)

Comment: @Quantum_VS: Your web interface should work basing on some kind of a session (does it?). In the session you can keep the userId of created user and then on each next page just update SQLite row with choices user makes. I don't see what is the difficulty here. Does this help or is your problem something else?

Comment: @Googie Unfortunately it's not a web interface. Building desktop gui application in Qt/C++. I have class which is dedicated for user registration. The code for different pages are written in different classes. I want to know how I can store the user name in this situation. Is my problem clear?

Comment: @Quantum_VS: If on the first page you save initial user data into SQLite, then you can access it from any other page. Just: `SELECT max(ROWID) FROM your_table_name;` - and get the result ID as integer and use it later as: `UPDATE your_table_name SET column1 = value, column2 = value WHERE ROWID = theRowId` (where `theRowId` is the row id you read from the `SELECT` before). I assume that you can edit only one user at the same time. Otherwise this method will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Even though query "SELECT max(ROWID) FROM your_table_name" works fine, I am not able to retrieve the value of rowId from the query.
       
       QSqlQuery q;

       q.prepare("SELECT max(ROWID) FROM UserDetails");
       q.exec();
       qDebug()<<q.result(); // This is returning the address and   not the value.

Comment: You're using `QSqlQuery` in a wrong way. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html and see the examples on that page.